# Scipy create sparse row matrix from a list of indices and a list of list data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

suppose I have a list of list data, and a list containing the row number of each data, how to convert to a sparse matrix?

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
indices = np.array([0,0,4]) # row number, sum when duplicated
```

expected output is:

```py
[[5, 7, 9], # row 0: [5,7,9]=[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [7, 8, 9]] # row 4
```

I understand that I can construct it using `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` with data, and row, col, or indptr, but I now have already calculated `data` and `indices`, is there a way to simply construct a sparse matrix using these two? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [131]: data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
     ...: indices = np.array([0,0,3]) # row number, sum when duplicated
```

I corrected the indices for 0 based indexing.

We don't need `sparse` to sum the duplicates.  There's a `np.add.at` that does this nicely:

```
In [135]: res = np.zeros((4,3),int)
In [136]: np.add.at(res, indices, data)
In [137]: res
Out[137]: 
array([[5, 7, 9],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

If we make a `csr` from that:

```
In [141]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(res)
In [142]: M
Out[142]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [143]: M.data
Out[143]: array([5, 7, 9, 7, 8, 9])
In [144]: M.indices
Out[144]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [145]: M.indptr
Out[145]: array([0, 3, 3, 3, 6], dtype=int32)
```

To make a `csr` directly, it's often easier to use the `coo` style of inputs.  They are easier to understand.

Those inputs are 3 1d arrays of the same size:

```
In [160]: data.ravel()
Out[160]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [161]: row = np.repeat(indices,3)
In [162]: row
Out[162]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3])
In [163]: col = np.tile(np.arange(3),3)
In [164]: col
Out[164]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
In [165]: M1 = sparse.coo_matrix((data.ravel(),(rows, cols)))
In [166]: M1.data
Out[166]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

The `coo` format leaves the inputs as given; but on conversion to `csr` duplicates are summed.

```
In [168]: M2 = M1.tocsr()
In [169]: M2
Out[169]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [170]: M2.data
Out[170]: array([5, 7, 9, 7, 8, 9])
In [171]: M2.indices
Out[171]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [172]: M2.indptr
Out[172]: array([0, 3, 3, 3, 6], dtype=int32)

In [173]: M2.A
Out[173]: 
array([[5, 7, 9],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

@Erik shows how to use the `csr` format directly:

```
In [174]: M3 =sparse.csr_matrix((data.ravel(), col, [0,6,6,6,9]))
In [175]: M3
Out[175]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [176]: M3.A
Out[176]: 
array([[5, 7, 9],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [177]: M3.indices
Out[177]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Note this has 9 nonzero elements; it hasn't summed the duplicates for storage (though the `.A` display shows them summed).  To sum, we need an extra step:

```
In [179]: M3.sum_duplicates()
In [180]: M3.data
Out[180]: array([5, 7, 9, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), there is a constructor that utilizes the CSR information directly:

```
csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)])
```

So in your specific case, you could write it like:

```
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
indices = np.array([0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]) # col numbers
indptr = np.array([0,6,6,6,9]) # row pointers

mat = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(4, 3))
```

To get an example on how the CSR format works, you can take a look into [sparse matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). I will explain the code nonetheless:

First, the `data` needs to be flattened to a single list. The `indices` of the CSR format relate to the *column*-indices, while the `indptr` is used to point to the *rows*.

So having an `indptr` value of `0` at **position** `0` in the list tells us that the 1st row `(position + 1)` of the matrix starts after `0` `data` entries. Similarly, a value of `6` at **position** `1` in the list tells us that the 2nd row `(position + 1)` of the matrix starts after `6` `data` entries.

The column-indices list is as you would expect it to behave: `data[i]` is positioned in column `indices[i]`.

Comment: You might want to add `mat.sum_duplicates()` step.